# Freemarker template to check the constant value

Tags: java, freemarker

Here is my piece of code

```
<#if (miscValue_index > 0)><#break></#if>
<td valign=""top"">${miscValue.propertyName!}</td>
<td width=""10px"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign=""top"">${miscValue.propertyValue!}</td>
<td width=""10px"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign=""top"">${miscValue.newPropertyValue!}</td>
<td width=""10px"">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

i want to check if "*miscValue.propertyValue*" value is UNDEFINED or valid string

miscValue.propertyValue will return a valid string or UNDEFINED.
If the value returned is "UNDEFINED",i need to update "empty string" else the "orginal value" using freemarker language.Could anyone please help on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: In the above image,instaed of UNDEFINED ,i need to update a blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this:

`<#if variable_to_test??>not null!<#else>null!</#if>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something as below,

```
<#if value?? >
$value
<#if/>

<#if value?? >
$value
<#else>

<#if/>
```

Here value can be a token that you want to verify. You can add <#else> tag if you want to print something else like blank space in case value is not valid as mentioned in second example.

Comment: <td valign=""top""><#if ${miscValue.propertyValue!}=="UNDEFINED"> </#if><#if ${miscValue.propertyValue!}!="UNDEFINED">${miscValue.propertyValue!} </td>                                    is this one is correct?

Comment: I think direct space should do. Or you can use right_pad to add empty space. https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_right_pad